# Is there a way to allow users to create NFC shortcuts in-app? (without going to shortcuts)

Tags: swift, nfc, shortcut, sirishortcuts

I want users to be able to pair an NFC tag within my app to create shortcut to get to a certain view within the app. I would like to achieve this without the user having to leave the app and set it up in shortcuts.

I know the McDonalds app allows a user to create a Siri voice shortcut from within the app using "when I say". Is there a way to do the same with the "when I scan" intent?